# Can layout thrashing cause incorrect painting?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rendering

I was working on a toy project recently where I wanted to put the radix right after the number itself. My first attempt was to use `<input>`/`<textarea>` (I have turned to contenteditable `<div>` now). Because there is no easy way to size `<input>` and `<textarea>` to make it fit tightly to its content, I used `<div>` elements as helpers, which have the same content as the `<input>`/`<textarea>` I want to resize.

The weird thing I encountered is that in initial rendering, the painted results are not correct, even if the width and height of `<input>` and `<textarea>` correspond to the referenced `<div>` element.

A demonstration of this problem can be found [on this codepen](https://codepen.io/kumom/pen/KKNBYjL). (Note: you might need to force reload the page if you want to reproduce the behavior. In addition, the number of incorrect results depends on the type of device in my case.)

I first suspected this only happened for non-monospaced fonts, but as demonstrated in the codepen link above, this behavior also persists for monospaced fonts.

I know what I am doing leads to layout thrashing, but when I use Chrome's dev tools and peek at the intermediate generated frames, the painted results are still incorrect. Based on my understanding of thrashing in general, it is just a performance issue and shouldn't lead to incorrect results. Or can it be in the case of layout thrashing?

P.S. Don't want to cause too much digression, but I didn't observe "Cutive Mono" causing this issue in React whereas "Montserrat" did. That's why I first suspected the issue has to do with typeface.